# How to safely harden the inner thigh

Tags: health, safety

I recently started kick-boxing training and last time there was an exercise in which we had to deliver low round kicks to the partner's outer and inner thigh. The kicks were half power and I did not experience excess pain, however, the next day I had a big (10cm x 20cm) dark purple-blue spot on my right inner thigh (nothing on the outside, or on the left leg, just the right inner thigh).

I have three questions:

1. I'm worried about possible health effects of doing this regularly. I accept that hardening the body is important, but I am worried about the health of the veins in my inner thigh. I do not have any health problems right now (eg. no visible varicose veins), and I assume that if I continue to train like this, the symptoms will be less and less until eventually my body gets hardened. Is this true?
2. Are there any long term negative health effects of getting kicked in the inner thigh often?
3. What are the best exercises for strengthening the inner parts of the thighs? I have strong, visible muscles on the front and the outside of my thighs, but less so on the inside. Generally, what's the safest way to harden that part of the body?

Comment: -1, are you seriously asking for medical advise from the Internet?  +1, for your last question (3) which is interesting.

Comment: Side kicks? Or round kicks?

Comment: @Sardathrion: Read carefully, I'm not asking for medical advice. I'd have gone to the doctor with that. I didn't, because I'm sure this particular bruise will go away. But a doctor will not be able to tell about the mid-long term effects of training. A regular doctor would probably say stop doing it, if they lack first-hand experience, because they always want to stay on the safe side. Hence, I asking it here from people with experience.

Comment: First, you **are** asking about medical advise -- see *I'm worried about possible health effects[...]* and *Are there any long term negative health effect[...]*.  Second, the assertion that *"[...] a doctor will not be able to tell about the mid-long term effects of training."* **is wrong.** Yes, a doctor should be able to tell you of negative effects of injuries.  You might have to find a doctor that specialise in sport and sport injuries for more up to date information but any medical doctor will be able to tell.  They are certainly more qualified that random strangers on the Internet.

Comment: some bruising will be expected initially, but serious bruising and regularly being hurt shows bad training techniques and might mean you need to find a different teacher.  I believe in the saying: Gradual Progress. Build up hardness/toughness slowly and gently over time without serious injury to yourself.

Comment: I have to agree with Sardathrion. If you are injured go seek the advice from a doctor or physiotherapist. Try to find someone specialized in sports injuries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toughen up. It's a bruise. You'll stop getting bruised after doing it a few months. I've never heard even the suggestion that there are long-term negative health effects of this kind of mild conditioning. If you don't want to get bruised, or if you suspect that bruises are indicative of some deeper danger, then kickboxing is not a good choice for you.

If the bruise is really deep (like a bone bruise) from a massive impact, you could get some [permanent deformations](http://forums.mtbr.com/womens-lounge/there-any-long-term-effects-bruises-45418.html) that show you the bruise was there. I have bumpy shins from shin-on-shin clashes at karate. It's a merely cosmetic reminder.

The best way to harden the inner and outer thigh is to get kicked there in drills and in sparring, sometimes with the opponent wearing shinguards, sometimes not. It couldn't hurt to do some weighted squats and lunges outside of class too.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not against bruises in general, I was asking specifically about the inner thighs. Some important stuff runs there, the femoral artery, the great saphenous vein, the sciatic nerve. But if experience tells that these are not of concern (given tough, but sensible training) and it all just toughens up without negative consequences, then I believe it.

Comment: Actually, the bumps in the shin produced by impact are because you have damaged the periosteum in the area, and it doesn't reform the bone in the same way in that area. Cortical remodeling goes on all the time.